# ccp & cpv - function difference & full form of cocoa

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have following code in my Application.

I am new to game development in iPhone using COCOS.

```
Sprite *bg=[Sprite spriteWithFile:@"menu.png"];
    [bg setPosition:ccp(240,160)];
    [self addChild:bg z:0];
    [self addChild:[GameLayer node] z:1];
}
return self;
```

}

```
@end
@implementation GameLayer
-(id)init{
    if(self=[super init]){
        Label *test=[Label labelWithString:@"Hello World" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:24];
        test.position=cpv(160, 240);
        test.visible=YES;
        [self addChild:test];
    }
    return self;
}
```

What is the function of ccp & cpv?
( I think it is for setting the layer's position, But I am not sure. So I am Asking)

Sagar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the source code:

From [CGPointExtension.h](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#PWa7F9gP7VU/trunk/cocos2d/Support/CGPointExtension.h&q=define%20ccp%20package:http://cocos2d-iphone%5C.googlecode%5C.com)

```
#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

From [cpVect.h](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=9&ct=rc#PWa7F9gP7VU/trunk/external/Chipmunk/src/cpVect.h&q=define%20cpv%20package:http://cocos2d-iphone%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=30)

```
#define cpVect CGPoint
static inline cpVect cpv(const cpFloat x, const cpFloat y)
{
        cpVect v = {x, y};
        return v;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

ccp is a simple macro defined by COCOS to easily create a CGPoint. So it's nothing more than just a point (x,y coordinate) It is defined as:

```
#define ccp(__X__,__Y__) CGPointMake(__X__,__Y__)
```

*position* is a property of the Label object, which probably sets the position on the screen to the point created by `ccp()`. I don't know which corner is being used as a reference point (center/top-left/bottom-left?) as I've never used COCOS so please try that yourself.

Good luck